# Control Chromecast Audio volume with a wall dimmer and RasPi

Tags: raspbian, chromecast

I want to develop a Wi-Fi enabled wall volume "dimmer" switch that can control the volume on a Chromecast Audio. I was thinking of using a Lutron Caseta switch and trapping the changes with a Pi that would then control the Chromecast. I am new to this community so please direct me if this or something similar has been solved.

I have not used the Lutron... Is there a better choice? I know I can control apps and google home already. But I have elderly people who just want a switch on the wall.

Any suggestions? Do I need a hub to use the Lutron or can the Pi do it by itself?

Comment: This seems like an over-engineered solution why not just use or replicate the remote control of the TV?

Comment: Interesting. So attach a remote... what remote controls the volume of a chromecast audio?

Comment: No the remote that comes with whatever device the chroimecasts is connected to (TV most likely). Presumably, it has a remote control, you could clone the IR signal and replay it from a button connected to the Pi

Comment: Thanks.  The chromecast audio is a separate product from the chromecast.  It does not connect to a tv.

Answer (score 0):

You can interface $_anything to mkchromecast, by opening it as a process you pipe data to (e.g. perl's `open(FH, "| command -arg1 -arg2=foo")`, `perldoc -f open` ) . IIRC it uses keys to lower and raise volume, and is itself a python script - so it is easy to modify these keys. You can get it here: http://mkchromecast.com/

As for the dimmer, you don't have an ADC on the Pi, but you can use an arduino and 433MHz module to send to the Pi. This would cost about $5. Or perhaps a HAT. Find some point in the dimmer device that outputs a voltage that correlates nicely to light level, and if necessary drop it with zener diodes to below 5V at maximum brightness.

Edit: 
The Chromecast supports (on TVs that support CEC/AnyNet) at least play/pause/stop, and perhaps also raise/lower volume.